# scrollTop issues in jQuery, some work others dont

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've spent a few days browsing for an answer on this. I've got 3 divs that have 3 corresponding buttons above them. (Steveaolsen.com homepage). They all hide on documentReady per the jQuery. Then when you click the button you want the corresponding div pops up under it, using fadeIn on jQuery. It's all under the documentReady function and each button has it's own onClick function. I've also crammed some scrollTop functions under each of the onClick functions (so each onClick for each button has 2 commands, run fadeIn then run scrollTop.)

So the first 2 work fine. The third fades in but I get no scrollTop on it. This is my question. Why does the fadeIn on all 3 work but the scrollTop on only the first 2 work?

Second question, more of an annoyance: why does my scrollTop not accept parameters to move up and down y axis. I kinda want all three boxes center of screen, the second one is lower than the first and (obviously) per above the third is hopelessly not even scrolling to.

Thank you

Comment: Please note my website steveaolsen.com has the jQuery for the hide and fade in which all works great. My code for scrollTop is not live yet as I'm trying to work it out. I can paste if needed.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but is your 3rd section tall enough to scroll to without hitting the bottom of the document?

Comment: It's on the very bottom of the page. But shouldn't a scrollTop at least push it to the top (as much as possible) you could be right. My logic: when the divs are all hidden they are all close to the bottom. However the 3rd div is at the dead end of the page. No other elements below it. I tried adding a footer to get around it but when I did that I had it jump (scrollTop) to the footer.

Is adding a footer then having it scrollTop the div a workaround?

I can try it when I get home and uodate

Comment: I would try throwing something at the end of the page just to see if that's the issue! I might be remembering incorrectly but I seem to recall that the animation not completing (if hitting the bottom of the document stops it), prevents any associated callbacks from firing.

Comment: i put about 50 line breaks in it, then a paragraph <p> at the end. no luck.

Comment: So just to make sure I'm understanding this right, the intended functionality is: click a button (web/marketing/personality), that section fades in, then you get scrolled to the top of it?

Comment: Thats exactly what I'm trying to do will : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will do the trick!

```
$('[id*="show"]').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).next('div').fadeIn();
  $('body, html').animate({
    scrollTop: $(this).offset().top - $('.navBar').height()
  }, 500)
});
```

Comment: worked like a charm!!! thank you sir!!!

ive got a floating "<" at the bottom of the page which seems to act as some kind of marker. not a major issue.

Comment: im new to stackO, let me know how to rep you up and i will.

Comment: You can mark this as the approved answer! You need to meet some prerequisite to rep up

Comment: Marked. Thanks again will